# Splitting multiple columns of text into different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stringr

I have a column that looks like the following dataset:

```
Initial_Data 3Mo_Data 6Mo_Data Irrelevant_Col1 Irrelevant_Col2
18/24        14/14    NA       1               1
4/24         NA       6/14     0               0

df <- structure(list(Initial_Data = c("18/24", "4/24"), `3Mo_Data` = c("14/14", 
NA), `6Mo_Data` = c(NA, "6/14"), Irrelevant_Col1 = 1:0,     Irrelevant_Col2 = 1:0), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

And I'd like to split it in such a way to identify all the columns of "Data" and then split them into three columns:

1. One with the fraction (originally a character variable), expressed as a decimal.
2. Second column with the numerator
3. Third new column with the denominator

while ignoring the irrelevant columns so as to look like the following:

```
Initial_Data 3Mo_Data 6Mo_Data Irrelevant_Col1 Irrelevant_Col2 Inial_Data_Numerator  Initial_Data_Denominator 3Mo_Data_Numerator 3Mo_Data_Denominator 6Mo_Data_Numerator 6Mo_Data_Denominator 
0.75         1        NA       1               1               18                    24                       14                 14                   NA                 NA
0.17         NA       0.43     0               0               4                     24                       NA                 NA                   6                  14
```

I tried something like the following just to generate the numerator and denominator columns:

```
test <- df %>%
  mutate(across(contains("Data"),
         ~ paste0(.x, "Numerator") = str_extract(., "^\\d+"),
         ~ paste0(.x, "Denominator") = str_extract(.,"(?<=\\D)\\d+"))
```

But gives me errors with the equal sign, perhaps I'm not able to use paste0 in this way?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I added the dput to recreate the table Tim. I think it should be okay, but if it doesn't line up with yours then change it to fit :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` workflow:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidy)

df %>%
  separate_wider_delim(ends_with("Data"), delim = '/',
                       names_sep = '_', names = c("Num", "Denom")) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("Num"), as.numeric, .names = "{sub('_Num', '', .col)}") /
         across(ends_with("Denom"), as.numeric),
         .before = 1)

# # A tibble: 2 × 11
#   Initial_Data `3Mo_Data` `6Mo_Data` Initial_Data_Num Initial_Data_Denom `3Mo_Data_Num` `3Mo_Data_Denom` `6Mo_Data_Num` `6Mo_Data_Denom` Irrelevant_Col1 Irrelevant_Col2
#          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>            <chr>              <chr>          <chr>            <chr>          <chr>                      <int>           <int>
# 1        0.75           1     NA     18               24                 14             14               NA             NA                             1               1
# 2        0.167         NA      0.429 4                24                 NA             NA               6              14                             0               0
```

Another presentation of `mutate()` that uses `cur_column()` within `across()`:

```r
df %>%
  separate_wider_delim(ends_with("Data"), delim = '/',
                       names_sep = '_', names = c("Num", "Denom")) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("Num"),
                ~ as.numeric(.x) / as.numeric(get(sub("Num", "Denom", cur_column()))),
                .names = "{sub('_Num', '', .col)}"),
         .before = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, using `separate_wider_delim`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- separate_wider_delim(df, cols= c("Initial_Data", "3Mo_Data", "6Mo_Data"), delim = "/", names_sep = "_")
colnames(df) <- str_replace_all(colnames(df), c("_1$" = "_Numerator", "_2$" = "_Denominator"))
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for such a quick reply! What would be the best way within this function to capture all columns with "Data" rather than typing it out individually? The actual dataset has many more columns of "Data" and I'd like to use something like across(contains("Data")) in order to capture all those columns without specifying them individually.

Comment: you can do `select(df, contains("Data"))`, or `df %>% select(contains("Data"))`
(equivalent), or a myriad of base R ways

Comment: Thanks alot Mark - appreciate the response. Does a nice job capturing and separating the numerator and denominator using separate_wider_delim. Will mark Darren's as complete as it puts it exactly as done in the answer. Thanks for taking the time on this!